# How to manually install text-to-speech voice packages in OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, audio, text-to-speech, text-to-speech-voices

it's nice to have the text-to-speech voice in OS X. I can easily read and listen to two articles at the same time (my "super" brain works that way)!

I am wondering tho, where is the voice packages stored in the OS X. I downloaded the US voice package "Samantha," and her voice is the most fluent amount all over computer voices. It's around 500MB. I was wondering if I can just copy it over to my laptop instead of using my slow home internet connection to download it again - which would take up to 4 or 5 hours - and often fail in the progress.

Thanks!

Also, can I install over voice packages such as ones from NeoSpeech? Their voices have higher speed so I can listen to articles faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. They are over at system/library/speech/voices

Hope this helps.